# R: Specifying a dataframe argument in a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to add a new column to a dataframe, however I need to create many columns for 5 or so dataframes. So I want to write a function. Since all the columns will be the same for each dataframe, this is what I had in mind:

```
 n = c(2,3,5)
 f = c("two", "three", "five")
 q = c(1,1.5,2.5)
 df= data.frame(n,f,q)
 fxn_foo <- function(x){
      x$egret <- (x$n)/2
 }

 fxn_foo(df)

 df$egret
```

Why does this produce `Null`? Are my arguments misspecified? Do I need to specify that the argument is a dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `return` statement:

```
fxn_foo <- function(x){
  x$egret <- (x$n)/2
  return(x)
  }
```

Then

```
df <- fxn_foo(df)
```